# rest service based on Spring return html instead of json

Tags: json, spring, rest

i am using keycloak and spring to get the user list in a rest service, however the rest return the html instead of json data.

here is the service.

```
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    @Autowired
    KeycloakInstance keycloakInstance;

    
    public List<UserRepresentation> loadUsers(String realm) {
        return keycloakInstance.getInstance()
                .realm(realm)
                .users()
                .list();
    }
}
```

here is the controller.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation;

import java.util.List;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/admin/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "", produces="application/json") 
    public List<UserRepresentation> loadUsers() {
        String realm = "abc";
        return userService.loadUsers(realm);
    }
}
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: are you sure your controller is called correctly? or does the filter chain redirect you to some other page? you could try to debug a call to the loadUsers-method. if your call works you should check you have a bean of type HttpMessageConverter for the media type application/json in your classpath. Can you provide more details about your application setup?

Comment: What difference is the @ResponseBody annotation added below @GetMapping(value = "", produces="application/json") does? Does it give a JSON you need?

Comment: @Ashish it is not returning json but a html

Comment: The empty path of the method `loadUsers`() seems to lead Spring to use the Controller parameter which is left to the default value. Setting the default of the Controller with something like: `@RequestMapping("/api/admin/users", produces="application/json")` sets all methods to return `json` unless overridden.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to add the path to `@GetMapping`, this should work

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = "/api/admin/users", produces="application/json") 
public List<UserRepresentation> loadUsers() {
        String realm = "abc";
        return userService.loadUsers(realm);
}
```

or using this way

```
 @GetMapping (value = "/api/admin/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ConstantinKonstantinidis commented, add to `RequestMapping` [produces](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--) JSON to apply to your method (and all methods):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/admin/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

> **Supported at the type level as well as at the method level**

Another option is to add the path to `@GetMapping` ,e.g.

```
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/users", produces="application/json")
```